# compiler isnt identifying getline() . moreover it isn't letting cin and cout use strings as well

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been programming since 3 years in c++. I have used compilers like turbo c++, Dev c++, linux & codeblocks.

Recently, I started using Visual Studio 2014 C++ and I'm facing a problem with strings.

```
using namespace std;

int main()    
{
   string s;
   cout << "enter string: ";
   getline(cin, s);
   cout << s;
   return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler isn't identifying `getline`. Moreover, it isn't letting `cin` and `cout` use strings as well. The code seems to work with other compilers (e.g. Turbo C++, Dev C++, Linux, CodeBlocks), but it doesn't compile on Visual Studio.

I'm totally confused what could be the problem here.

Comment: Did you `#include` `<string>`?

Comment: And `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @RSahu That's not the problem, `getline` accepting `string` is defined in `<string>`. [Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). By the way, I wasn't aware of existence of `visual studio 2014`.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek OP cannot even use `cout` or `cin` without `#include <iostream>`. So, it is part of the problem.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Both need to be included, since `<iostream>` may just use a forward declaration for `std::string`.

Comment: i knw abt #include<iostream> & didnt mention as i thot every1 wud understand.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek you r right
i was using 2013 version, that was a type erratum :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `#include <iostream>`. Without this, you cannot use `std::cout` or `std::cin`. Also, you need `#include <string>` to use `std::getline()` and `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()    
{
   string s;
   cout<<"enter string: ";
   getline(cin,s);
   cout<<s;
   return 0;
}
```

You can also put `system("pause");` before the `return` statement to have it pause when it prints the output, in case you wanted to see it.

Comment: i had included #include<iostream> & #include<string.h> . i didnt mention the these as i thought it's obvious and people would understand.

Comment: however the  code runs in <string> & not in <string.h>. what is the difference between these 2 ?
one more question, i had read that using system commands is not the sign of a good programmer ? is it true ?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya `string.h` contains old functions like strcpy, strlen.
`<string>` primarily contains the `std::string` class (which is what you need for `getline()`). Also, its wrong to assume we would understand when you show `using namespace std;` but no includes. Please mark answer as correct if it solved your question. Thanks

Comment: with system commands i meant system("pause"), system ("cls"), etc
string.h works in dev c++ however